# Analyse time complexity in terms of Big theta

Tags: complexity-theory

I've been trying to set up clear information on iterating through and i and then j, but i get stuck when trying to make sense of the while loop? 
Can someone please give me some information on how to solve something like this please?

Comment: Why exactly are you stuck on that while loop? What don't you understand or are confused by?

Comment: I don't entirely understand the process of how to define the running time of an algorithm. Bonje Fir exactly gives me a perfect explanation, but I hope that is enough to show that it is Big Theta (n^2) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: this answer is long and overly verbose because I wanted to provide the OP with a "baby-steps" method rather than a result. I hope she can find some help from it - would it be needed.*

If you get stuck when trying to derive the complexity in one go, you can try to breakdown the problem into smaller pieces easier to reason about.
Introducing notations can help in this context to structure your thought process.

1. Let's introduce a notation for the inner `while` loop. We can see the starting index `j` depends on `n - i`, so the number of operations performed by this loop will be a function of `n` and `i`. Let's represent this number of operations by `G(i, n)`.
2. The outer loop depends only on `n`. Let's represent the number of operations by `T(n)`.
3. Now, let's write down the dependency between `T(n)` and `G(n, i)`, reasoning about the outer loop only - we do not care about the inner `while` loop for this step because we have already abstracted its complexity in the function `G`. So we go with:

   `T(n) = G(n, n - 1) + G(n, n - 2) + G(n, n - 3) + ... + G(n, 0) 
         = sum(k = 0, k < n, G(n, k))`
4. Now, let's focus on the function `G`.

   - Let's introduce an additional notation and write `j(t)` the value of the index `j` at the  `t`-th iteration performed by the `while` loop.
   - Let's call `k` the value of `t` for which the invariant of the while loop is breached, i.e. the last time the condition is evaluated.
   - Let's consider an arbitrary `i`. You could try with a couple of specific values of `i` (e.g. 1, 2, `n`) if this helps.

We can write:

```
    j(0) = n - i
    j(1) = n - i - 3
    j(2) = n - i - 6
     ...
j(k - 1) = n - i - 3(k - 1)   such that j(k-1) >= 0 
    j(k) = n - i - 3k         such that   j(k) < 0
```

Finding `k` involves solving the inequality `n - 1 - 3k < 0`. To make it easier, let's "ignore" the fact that `k` is an integer and that we need to take the integer part of the result below.

```
n - i - 3k < 0 <=> k = (n - i) / 3
```

So there are `(n - i) / 3` "steps" to consider. By steps we refer here to the number of evaluation of the loop condition. The number of times the operation `j <- j - 3` is performed would be the latter minus one.

So we found an expression for `G(n, i)`:

```
G(n, i) = (n - i) / 3
```

Now let's get back to the expression of `T(n)` we found in (3):

```
T(n) = sum(k = 0, k < n, (n - k) / 3)
```

Since when `k` varies from 0 to `n`, `n - k` varies from `n` to 0, we can equivalently write `T(n)` as:

```
T(n) = sum(k = 0, k <= n, k / 3)
     = (1/3).sum(k = 0, j <= n, k)
     = (1/6).n.(n+1)
```

And you can therefore conclude with

```
T(n) = Theta(n^2)
```

This resolution exhibited some patterns from which you can create your own recipe to solve similar exercises:

- Consider the number of operations at individual levels (one loop at a time) and introduce notations for the functions representing them;
- Find relationships between these functions;
- Find an algebraic expression of the most inner functions, which doesn't depend on other functions you introduced and for which the number of steps can be calculated from a loop invariant;
- Using the relationships between these functions, find expressions for the functions higher in the stack.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 1):

In order to calculate all time-complexity of code, replace each loop with a summation. Moreover, consider that the second loop run `(n - i)/3` since `j` decreases with step size of `3`. So we have:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Sorry but how does the summation of i equal to (n*(n+1))/2?

Comment: @its_erc You are right. It is more accurate to say that big-Theta instead of big-O. So there is no need to prove lower bound.

Comment: @its_erc look at [this](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/) link. Part **Sum of First `n` Positive Integers**. Just look at the image :)

Comment: Oh my goodness thanks heaps. This is my first go at learning this stuff, its quite hard to find such good sources!